# function componentDidMount not firing in react native

Tags: react-native

The function componentDidMount is not firing.

This is some of my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Block } from 'galio-framework';

export function FriendRequests ( ) {

    const username = 'abcd';

    componentDidMount = () => {
        alert("abcd");
    }

    return (
    line number 37:    <Block>....</Block>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the functional component which doesn't have the lifecycle methods.

**Solution 1:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class FriendRequests extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

 componentDidMount = () => {
        alert("abcd");
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> Your text Here </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default FriendRequests;
```

**Solution 2:**

If you want to use it as functional component then you can use the `React Hook`  and can make use of `useEffect()` method from the hook instead of  `componentDidMount`. method to handle after render stuff.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

```
export function FriendRequests ( ) {


    componentDidMount = () => {
        alert("abcd");
    }

    return (
        ....
    )
}
```

this is a functional component, and functional component dont have any inbuilt functions like componentDidMount. Only class based components have access, So try this:

UPDATE:

```
export class FriendRequests extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        alert("abcd");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>hey</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: I am getting this error: Unexpected token (37:2). See line number 37 in my question.